# Unusual performance of libblas-dev on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package-management, performance

The package `libblas-dev` seems to have unusual performance (much faster) in some cases in the following question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042451/cblas-gemm-time-dependent-on-input-matrix-values

The similar performance improvement can not be observed in other BLAS packages on other platforms.

Anyone can help explain it? Feel free to amend the question/tags.

Comment: I'm not sure, if you gonna get answer here if you are comparing Ubuntu to other distributions. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) may be the more convenient. I don't have any sight on this topic, but you may check patches applied on packaging. `apt-get source libblas-dev` to get source then check `debian/patches` folder. Btw, Are comparing same version of the library, build for same architecture and  with same build parameters (check `debian/rules` ).